# post Ajax data but returned null

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, null

i'm making an ERP system for my company.
i want to make a searching function with multiple search words which is typed as tag shape.

this is the one i followed: http://demo.webslesson.info/bootstrap-tags-input-with-php/

and this is my code:

```
 <div class="form-gruop">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="text" id="tags" class="form-control" data-role="tagsinput" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <button type="button" name="search" class="btn btn-primary" id="search">>>SEARCH</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        <br>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <div allign="right">
                <p><b>Total Records - <span id="total_records"></span></b></p>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thread>
                    <tr>
                        <th>No.</th>
                        <th>BRAND</th>
                        <th>SHOE STYLE</th>
                        <th>COLOR</th>
                        <th>SHOE IMAGE</th>
                        <th>SG SHOE ID</th>
                        <th>CUST SHOE ID</th>
                        <th>PD TYPE</th>
                        <th>SIZE TYPE</th>
                       
                    </tr>
                </thread>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    load_data();

    function load_data(query)
    {
        $.ajax({
        url:"./fetch_pd_list.php",
        method: "post",
        data: {query:query},
        dataType: "JSON",

        success: function(data){
        //    $('#total_records').text(data.length);
            var html = '';
                    
            console.log(data);
            if (data===null) {null.length='0'};
            if (data.length > 0) {
                for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++) {
                    html += '<tr>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].no+'</td>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].brand_name+'</td>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].style_name+'</td>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].color_name+'</td>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].pd_image+'</td>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].sg_code+'</td>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].cust_code+'</td>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].production_type+'</td>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].size_type_name+'</td></tr>'; 
                }
            } else {
                    html = '<tr><td colspan="5">No Data Found</td></tr>';
            } 
            $('tbody').html(html);
        }, 
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
        })
    }

$('#search').click(function(){
    var query = $('#tags').val();
    load_data(query);
});

});
</script>
```

this is my 'fetch_pd_list.php' file.
(in the beginning, I included connection information as '$conn'.

```
$query = '';


if(isset($_POST["query"])) {
    $search = str_replace(",", "|", $_POST["query"]);
    $query = "SELECT @ROWNUM := @ROWNUM + 1 AS ROWNUM, A.*
                FROM 
                (SELECT product_no, brand_name, style_name, color_name, pd_image, concat(sg_id, '-', sg_col_id) AS sg_id, concat(cust_id, '-', cust_col_id) AS cust_id, production_type, size_type_name
                FROM 03_style
                RIGHT OUTER JOIN 03_product ON 03_style.style_no=03_product.style_no
                LEFT OUTER JOIN 02_brand ON 03_style.brand_no=02_brand.brand_no
                LEFT OUTER JOIN 03_shoe_color ON 03_product.color_no=03_shoe_color.shoe_color_no
                LEFT OUTER JOIN 03_production_type ON 03_style.pdtype_no=03_production_type.production_type_no
                LEFT OUTER JOIN 03_size_type ON 03_size_type.size_type_no=03_style.size_type_no
                ORDER BY brand_name, style_name, color_name) AS A
                WHERE brand_name REGEXP '".$search."'
                OR style_name REGEXP '".$search."'
                OR color_name REGEXP '".$search."'";
} else {
    $query = "SELECT @ROWNUM := @ROWNUM + 1 AS ROWNUM, A.*
                FROM 
                (SELECT product_no, brand_name, style_name, color_name, pd_image, concat(sg_id, '-', sg_col_id) AS sg_id, concat(cust_id, '-', cust_col_id) AS cust_id, production_type, size_type_name
                FROM 03_style
                RIGHT OUTER JOIN 03_product ON 03_style.style_no=03_product.style_no
                LEFT OUTER JOIN 02_brand ON 03_style.brand_no=02_brand.brand_no
                LEFT OUTER JOIN 03_shoe_color ON 03_product.color_no=03_shoe_color.shoe_color_no
                LEFT OUTER JOIN 03_production_type ON 03_style.pdtype_no=03_production_type.production_type_no
                LEFT OUTER JOIN 03_size_type ON 03_size_type.size_type_no=03_style.size_type_no
                ORDER BY brand_name, style_name, color_name) AS A";
}

$statement = $conn->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statement))
{ $data[] = $row;}
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

when I enter some words on the search bar, i can see the 'query' data exist and sent finely to 'fetch_pd_list.php',
but returned value is always 'null' as checking on console.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQ7Nc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa1q7.png)

this is the most important function i want to make for my service.
can you please help me to solve this problem?

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in
" if (data===null) {null.length='0'}; " - you are returning a undefined length.
" if (data===null) {data.length='0'}; " - this is the right syntax.

also you should pass the data.length as a int not as a string.

Cheers

```
<script>
   
    
        function load_data(query)
        {
            $.ajax({
            url:"./fetch_pd_list.php",
            method: "post",
            data: {query:query},
            dataType: "JSON",
    
            success: function(data){
            //    $('#total_records').text(data.length);
                var html = '';
                        
                console.log(data);
                if (data===null) {data.length=0};
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++) {
                        html += '<tr>';
                        html += '<td>'+data[count].no+'</td>';
                        html += '<td>'+data[count].brand_name+'</td>';
                        html += '<td>'+data[count].style_name+'</td>';
                        html += '<td>'+data[count].color_name+'</td>';
                        html += '<td>'+data[count].pd_image+'</td>';
                        html += '<td>'+data[count].sg_code+'</td>';
                        html += '<td>'+data[count].cust_code+'</td>';
                        html += '<td>'+data[count].production_type+'</td>';
                        html += '<td>'+data[count].size_type_name+'</td></tr>'; 
                    }
                } else {
                        html = '<tr><td colspan="5">No Data Found</td></tr>';
                } 
                $('tbody').html(html);
            }, 
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
            })
        }
    
    $('#search').click(function(){
        var query = $('#tags').val();
        load_data(query);
    });
    

    </script>
```

Comment: `data.length` should be a number, not a string.

Comment: Better mention `load_data();` as well, or better still remove that call completely as its in the wrong place

Comment: also delete the document.ready func, on pageload, you dont pass the query argument to the function. Why you should load a search function without any data? :D

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `load_data();` below the `$(document).ready(function(){`. But the main cause of you problem is `dataType: "JSON",`. Because you're reading the content as and array. Also I recon that you're missing an `var format = JSON.parse(data);`

So it should look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function load_data(query)
    {
        $.ajax({
        url:"./fetch_pd_list.php",
        method: "post",
        data: {query:query},

        success: function(data){
            $('#total_records').text(data.length);
            var html = '';
            
            if(data != ''){
                var formatted = JSON.parse(data);
                if(formatted.length > 0){
                    for(var count = 0; count < formatted.length; count++) {
                        html += '<tr>';
                        html += '<td>'+formatted[count].no+'</td>';
                        html += '<td>'+formatted[count].brand_name+'</td>';
                        html += '<td>'+formatted[count].style_name+'</td>';
                        html += '<td>'+formatted[count].color_name+'</td>';
                        html += '<td>'+formatted[count].pd_image+'</td>';
                        html += '<td>'+formatted[count].sg_code+'</td>';
                        html += '<td>'+formatted[count].cust_code+'</td>';
                        html += '<td>'+formatted[count].production_type+'</td>';
                        html += '<td>'+formatted[count].size_type_name+'</td></tr>'; 
                    }
                } else {
                    html = '<tr><td colspan="5">No Data Found</td></tr>';
                }
            } else {
                html = '<tr><td colspan="5">No Data Found</td></tr>';
            }
            $('tbody').html(html);
        }, 
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
        })
    }

    $('#search').click(function(){
        var query = $('#tags').val();
        load_data(query);
    });

});
```